# Proving the sum of the 2 vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, analytic-geometry, vector-analysis

"I need to prove summing 2 vectors,
I'm given 3 points 
1)$O(0,0)$

2)$A(a_1,b_1)$

3)$B(a_2, b_2)$

and that $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2 > 0$. Using the Geometric Definition I need to define that the cordinates for the sum of the vectors $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OB}$ are $(a1+a2,b1+b2)$.

Comment: which are what? i will fix

Comment: 2 things unclear from your question: 1) is $(a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2)$ a point? 2) Do you want to prove that $(a_1+a_2, b_1+b_2)$ is the sum of vectors $OA$ and $OB$?

Comment: Yes , and i fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\vec{OA} = \vec{A} - \vec{O}$

$= (a_1, b_1) - (0,0)$

$= (a_1 - 0, b_1 - 0)$

$= (a_1, b_1)$

Similarly,

$\vec{OB} = \vec{B} - \vec{O}$

$= (a_2, b_2) - (0,0)$

$= (a_2, b_2)$

$\vec{AB} = \vec{OA} + \vec{OB}$

$= (a_1, b_1) + (a_2, b_2)$

$= (a_1 + a_2 , b_1 + b_2)$

Comment: is this the geometric definition that proves it?

Comment: Yes it is. Also see this http://www.suitcaseofdreams.net/Geometric_addition.htm